# integration test should use test/resources

Tags: maven, spring-boot

Under the `src/main/resources` i have `application.xml` and `data.sql` files, and under `src/test/resources` i have the same files but their content is different. the problem is that when i run my integration test, it processes both files under `src/test/resources` and `src/main/resources`.

What is the most effective way to make it process only `application.xml` and `data.sql` contained under `src/test/resources` when i execute integration test ?

Comment: How come? If files are named indenticly they should be shadowed by test resources - it is impossible to process both as both directories has the same output directory and as you know, there cannot be 2 files with the same name. Both resource directory are compiled into the same target space.

Comment: Agreed with @Antoniossss, so it makes me wonder: are these integration tests in the same module, or in a module dependent on the one you describe? Maybe you can just give a bit more background about your project setup. Also, how are you reading in this `application.xml`?

Comment: can you share your pom.xml so that we have clear picture of your set up